# Cannot upload new version of apps

Tags: appgallery

While updating new version of app it rejected with error : "the package name already exists. Please try another one (Error code: 90202134)"

Comment: Chanhe app package name. Error is very clearly. If com.myapp exists, change to com.myapp2

Answer (score 1):

You have might have created a Harmony OS application with  with same package name Same package name can't be used for android and harmony application.

Now to update to android application, you have delete above Harmony OS application. . If you can't find the app , Please follow the steps below:

1. You can switch to “My Project” find harmony project and application [Highlighted with “H”]  ,
2. Then delete it  under Project settings

[image]